# Trying to compile Asylia via its makefile, with MinGW... Wrong compiler? How to fix?

Tags: windows, cygwin, compile, mingw, makefile

I'm trying to compile [Asylia](https://github.com/Quent42340/Asylia) via its [makefile](https://github.com/Quent42340/Asylia/blob/master/Makefile), with MinGW... Am I using the wrong compiler?

It's seems MinGW is getting stuck on the square brackets in "$(BUILD):"... And square brackets in MinGW are a Unix / Bash thing...

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, basename C:/Users/Andy/Desktop/Asylia-master, ...) failed.
'[' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

Do I need Cygwin's  to run that?

Or some easy edits that I don't know, so MinGW can run the makefile properly?

---

Oh... MinGW hasn't been updated in years... If that's the issue, I guess my only solution is to install Cygwin's gcc-g++, and then figure out how to compile things with that?

Comment: Have you tried https://mingw-w64.org/ ? It is updated regularly

Comment: @matzeri - Oh! No, I haven't. Thanks for the link. I'll see how it goes.

Comment: @matzeri - Uhh... How do I run a makefile with it?

Comment: you should install the tools or http://www.msys2.org/ or https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/mingw-builds.

Comment: @matzeri - I got the installer from Sourceforge, and ran it. Now what?

Comment: The game builds with cygwin, but development is frozen and never finished https://github.com/Quent42340/Asylia/issues/42

Comment: @matzeri - I know it's stopped. I just want to see what it looks like... Which branch did you use? Master isn't working, for me...

Comment: Master builds fine in cygwin. Running requires X server

Comment: @matzeri - It's telling me that "/source/activities/Activity.cpp" doesn't exist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Cygwin 64 bit.

```
$ wget https://github.com/Quent42340/Asylia/archive/master.zip
$ unzip master.zip
Archive:  master.zip
dcef5e0bc1d5e8de891a9f6b5a538cd7c1a70283
   creating: Asylia-master/
...
   creating: Asylia-master/wiki/
finishing deferred symbolic links:
  Asylia-master/droid/assets/audio -> /home/quentin/Projects/Asylia/audio
  Asylia-master/droid/assets/data -> /home/quentin/Projects/Asylia/data
  Asylia-master/droid/assets/fonts -> /home/quentin/Projects/Asylia/fonts
  Asylia-master/droid/assets/graphics -> /home/quentin/Projects/Asylia/graphics
```

the last four are broken links as they should not be absolute links but relative one

```
  Asylia-master/audio == /home/quentin/Projects/Asylia/audio
  Asylia-master/data  == /home/quentin/Projects/Asylia/data
  Asylia-master/fonts == /home/quentin/Projects/Asylia/fonts
  Asylia-master/graphics == /home/quentin/Projects/Asylia/graphics
```

In any case we can also ignore the issue for the build

```
$ make
...
built ... Asylia-master
$ ls -lrt
total 49M
...
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 Marco Kein  38M Dec 27 22:39 Asylia-master.exe
```

To run from an Xterm

```
$ ./Asylia-master.exe
```

The package is directly depending only from SDL2 shared libraries

```
$ cygcheck ./Asylia-master.exe | grep "^  D"
  D:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll
  D:\cygwin64\bin\cygSDL2-2-0-0.dll
  D:\cygwin64\bin\cygSDL2_image-2-0-0.dll
  D:\cygwin64\bin\cygSDL2_mixer-2-0-0.dll
  D:\cygwin64\bin\cygSDL2_ttf-2-0-0.dll
```

So the following packages are needed

```
$ cygcheck -cd |grep SDL2
libSDL2-devel                           2.0.7-1
libSDL2_2.0_0                           2.0.7-1
libSDL2_image-devel                     2.0.2-1
libSDL2_image2.0_0                      2.0.2-1
libSDL2_mixer-devel                     2.0.2-1
libSDL2_mixer2.0_0                      2.0.2-1
libSDL2_ttf-devel                       2.0.14-1
libSDL2_ttf2.0_0                        2.0.14-1
```

plus of course `cygwin-devel`,`make` and the compiler

```
gcc-core                                7.3.0-3
gcc-g++                                 7.3.0-3
```